# Xcode, LLVM 4.1, NSMutableArray, unused block in loop crashes. Why?

Tags: xcode, loops, nsmutablearray, block, llvm

This is my first post. I apologize for mistakes.

I have a crash I can fix, but I don't understand why it crashes in the first place. I tried to reduce the code to the essentials to make it crash:

```
GCFTile *currentTile;
NSInteger repeatCount = 0;
do {

    currentTile = self.remainingTilesArray[0];
    if (repeatCount == 0) {

        [self.remainingTilesArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [self.remainingTilesArray addObject:currentTile];
    }
    void (^myBlock)() = ^{

        currentTile;
    };
    repeatCount++;
} while (repeatCount == 1);
```

I'm using Xcode 4.5.2, iOS 5, ARC. Also, it crashes only if the LLVM compiler optimization is set to "Fast" or above.

The code above will get and remove an object from an NSMutableArray, put it back, and then get another object from the array. *The code above will run without crashing*, but if I scan across all the elements in the array later (e.g., from a different method), then it crashes. It looks like a random memory address was added to the array (probably from the above call to addObject).

The above block should do nothing, but if I change it then there's no crash later. (E.g., empty block = no crash. Don't declare block as "myBlock" = no crash.) If I don't repeat the loop, there's no crash. If I don't add the object back, there's no crash. If I declare currentTile using __block or within the do loop, there's no crash.

I know blocks are "stack-local," but this block doesn't do anything! And it runs fine without compiler optimization.

Any idea what's going on?

EDIT (12-5-12): Someone asked for the crash log. I'm running in the simulator, so I don't know how to get that. But here's a little from the Debug Navigator:

```
#0  0x0140409b in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x00010931 in __33-[GCFGame checkThatTilesAreValid]_block_invoke_0 at /Users/geoffrey2/personal/projects/Color Fever/Color Fever/GCFGame.m:54
#2  0x01cb24a5 in __NSArrayEnumerate ()
#3  0x01cb2026 in -[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] ()
#4  0x01cb1f35 in -[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:] ()
#5  0x000108f6 in -[GCFGame checkThatTilesAreValid] at /Users/geoffrey2/personal/projects/Color Fever/Color Fever/GCFGame.m:52
```

and the main window shows this (plus more lines):

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x140408c:  movl   8(%esp), %ecx
0x1404090:  movl   4(%esp), %eax
0x1404094:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x1404096:  je     0x14040e8                 ; objc_msgSend + 92
0x1404098:  movl   (%eax), %edx
0x140409a:  pushl  %edi
0x140409b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi
```

The error is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, adddress=0x9).`

Comment: Are you sure that crash log is for the same crash you're experiencing with this code? It looks completely unrelated.

Comment: @KurtRevis: Yes, I just ran it. =) `checkThatTilesAreValid` is the method I call later to scan across `self.remainingTilesArray`. The method just tries to access a unique property of the `GCFTile` object. So if the array contains a non-tile, it should crash.